# How to model a HTML table with column per component in React?

Tags: reactjs

React components are awesome when we know how to separate the concern.
However, I find this case really hard to abstract.

```
    |    A    |    B    |    C    |
    |   A.a   |   B.a   |   C.a   |
    |   A.b   |   B.b   |   C.b   |
    |   A.c   |   B.c   |   C.c   |
```

I have the API that return 1 column per request, eg: [A.a, A.b, A.c]
so normally I will like A, B, C to be a React Component
and render it to it's parent component

However, in this case I cannot easily do that because of the html structure flavor tr per component, not per column.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: Use one of CSS grid layouts, for example twitter bootstrap. You could have some issues if columns will have different heights and you need them equally but it's doable after some tinkering.

Comment: Ideally you should separate things out so you have one react component per __row__. If you have different ajax responses for each column, then do all the requests and then map that into a horizontal table structure when passing to the individual table row components. If the data needs to update at all, if you set it to `state` then the same mapping function should run again.

Comment: quick hack: http://jsfiddle.net/0tk44f75/1
obviously you can divide it into extra components. not the most beautiful way of doing it though

Answer (score 0):

Iterate differently, iterate the properties! Use a "RowRenderer" component that loops through all the properties `.a`, `.b`, `.c` given that you know those beforehand. Per property, use a "CellRenderer" that takes an object like `A`, `B`, `C` and the iteration's property-name, and render the cell.